# Twilio Autopilot Actions sequence and Timeout configuration

Tags: twilio

Testing Twilio Autopilot behavior and features, I noticed the following @ task_creation:

1-Action->redirect_url(fetch JSON from app Server)

- I could not find a way to configure any timeout
- The action redirect_url (CallbackURL) is "blocking"
- assistant is in between states
- cannot SAY nor LISTEN
- Assistant goes to Fallback_Task after as much as 20+ seconds
- Meanwhile, dialog is blank (no SAY, no LISTEN... no action)

2-Action->SAY->then->redirect_url (fetch more JSON from app Server)

- The SAY action, which precedes the redirect_url action, will not "speak" until the Task has the complete picture (JSON), some of which is fetched with redirect_url
- Hence, I cannot use SAY to announce: "Please wait while I lookup some... with our Systems..." because the SAY is performed ONLY after app Server responded with the JSON needed to "complete" the actions_description
- Meanwhile, same as previous point #1. Blocking, no SAY, no LISTEN

**My question:** Is there any mechanism in place to prevent Dialog to "hang" in the event that the app Server is "hanging"? I am thinking of some sort of decoupled architecture where the Assistant configuration is self-reliant on its own and cannot be thrown-off by app Server malfunction/lag/. i.e. : some sort of timeout control on the Autopilot side.

**My tests:**

**Test 1** Created simple Task that fetches JSON from app Server using redirect_url (HTTP CALLBACK URL) option rather than ACTIONS BIN @ Task creation.

- Server side, I forced a long sleep(30sec), so server keeps socket connected but lags responding with JSON that would define the actions for this task
- Meanwhile, Dialog is hanging and Assistant is not responsive (nor LISTENing)
- After what seems to be 20 seconds, the assistant proceeds with default fallback task

  ```
  {
  "actions": [
      {
          "redirect": "https://www.myExampleAppServer.com/assistant_endpoint/"
      }
  ]}
  ```

**Test 2** Same as above but added SAY before redirect_url.

- The SAY will not "speak" until the response is received from app Server
- I lowered the sleep(10sec) server side to confirm the behavior, and it works as described in my question introduction. Dialog hangs for 10 seconds, then proceeds with the hard-coded SAY following with actions (JSON) received from app Server

  ```
  {
  "actions": [
      {
        "say": "Please Wait while I check with the central offices."
      },
      {
        "redirect": "https://www.myExampleAppServer.com/assistant_endpoint/"
      }
  ]}
  ```

I also tested different combinations using LISTEN, which is also Blocking, and could not help to un-block the assistant. i.e. : While hanging/waiting for app Server, could not find any structure where the Caller can ask : "Anybody there?" and trigger any new routing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I know Autopilot is BETA, but thought my question could still be pertinent while in BETA.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, are you asking if there's a way for an assistant to time out during long response times from your server so that it can send a message back to the user to say that it is calculating or fetching the answer and then continue with the conversation once it has the answer?

Comment: Being able to do an asynchronous response like you describe is not currently available. There might be some workarounds though. I'm just investigating a bit more and will hopefully come back with some ideas.

Comment: @philnash Thanks for your note. The async idea is interesting and I see how that would be challenging. As for my question, it is straight sync control of the Assistant configuration, being able to config a timeout when fetching actions from App Server. Just like a straight Curl timeout as one could use to route fallback. While testing Autopilot, I noticed that if the App Server is slow, there is no way for the Caller to be aware of any "please wait, working on it..." concept, and any hard-coded SAY, before fetch, is only executed after App Server's response. Hope this clarifies some bit.

Comment: This is what I mean by an asynchrnous response. You want to be able to send one response initially to say "Please wait" and then be able to interrupt again once the long running request has completed with the actual result. I'm waiting to hear from the Autopilot team about what they suggest here in the meantime though.

Comment: @philnash The SAY "please wait..." was an example of some flow. I think I am trying to evaluate some form of flow-control so that the Assistant is as fluid as possible. Just like when a phrase, that does not map to any NaturalLangRouting, would trigger some fallback task... A recognized phrase by the Model could fallback to some_task @ x seconds timeout? This, in order to keep the dialog flowing seamlessly?

Comment: @philnash More : Just tested stopping Apache on my App Server and Assistant hung without falling back to default tasks, for more than 90 seconds (I hung up @ 90s.) Then another test using an invalid/inexistant URL endpoint, and same behavior as first test. Perhaps my question should go to the "Later/after-beta" bin ;)